# Is there a way to keep popup.html open after oauth authorization in chrome extensions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, vue.js, google-chrome-extension

There are similar threads to this from many years ago, and as I have come across documentation saying that popups close after losing focus, I have seen an example of [a chrome extension that achieves this functionality](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/checker-plus-for-google-c/hkhggnncdpfibdhinjiegagmopldibha/related?hl=en). The functionality that I am specifically referring to is the ability to keep the popup open after authorization.

Currently I use the identity api and have implemented a sign in button for my chrome extension using the following code:

```
getAccessToken(interactive) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    browser.identity.getAuthToken({ interactive: interactive }, token => {
      resolve(token);
    });
  });
},
```

, but after the login dialogue is finished, my chrome extension popup immediately closes, which is a poor user experience.

Is there any current workaround for this? The extension I have references accomplishes this with oauth, but I have yet to see a solution online.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? currently facing the same issue.